# Run a process and find out that it was started

Tags: java, exe

I need to run `.exe` file, and after launching this file execute some script once the process is loaded and running, before it has terminated. So script will throw an exception if previous `.exe` is not fully loaded..

How I can know that `.exe` file is fully loaded?

I can use `Timer` to schedule script execution to some time, but it's not good idea, because `.exe`  file may still not be launched after some scheduling time.

Comment: What do you mean 'fully loaded'. Do you mean invoked and running ?

Comment: do you want to execute the script once the `exe` has started or after it has finished?

Comment: @BrianAgnew yes, I need event when Process is running.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @assylias yes, at start time.

Comment: i don't think there is 'running' state, maybe you can capture some output from Process, which will signal that it is running

Comment: @T.J.Crowder tried to use `Timer`.  It's work. But `Process` class don't have any methods to check it/

Comment: Did you write the .exe?  What is starting the .exe and script?  Do you have a single java program that kicks them off?

Comment: @jco.owens yes, I have a single Java program, that firstly try to run `.exe` file, and then try to run some script (which will operate with previously launched `.exe`)

Comment: @jco.owens I write an applet. Not `.exe`. I want to run `.exe` file on users machine using applet

Comment: @MyTitle - that sounds like a *very* bad idea, if if possible (and I think the security mechanism will stop you)

Comment: @BrianAgnew no, security mechanism don't stop me. And it's good. Another way is to use ActiveX. And it more buggy and unsecured way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) which handles a lot of the pain of process launching. In particular look at the [DefaultExecuteResultHandler](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecuteResultHandler.html), which will get a callback when the launched process exits. So long as you don't receive that callback your launched process is still running.

Note (in case it's not clear) that if your Java process launches an executable it will get an immediate callback when that process dies, provided `Process.waitFor()` has been called.

Comment: Thanks, but I need process-start event, not when process is die.

Answer (score 0):

As the last thing in your exe files duty create a file in a shared location. Check for the file from your other code. So that shared file will act as the lock.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the list of running processes regularly until you find the executable in the list - once you see it you know it has been launched.

Note: if the executable ends after 1 second for example, and you check the processes every 10 seconds, you might miss it.